# Error with drawing a Feynman Diagramm using axodraw4j package

Tags: diagrams, feynman

I am trying to draw a simple Feynman diagram but it does not get drawn correctly. When I compile it puts, the momentum labels without drawing the lines.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
  \begin{picture}(176,146) (183,-125)
    \SetWidth{1.0}
    \SetColor{Black}
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=16,arrowwidth=10,arrowinset=1](342,20)(270,-52)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=16,arrowwidth=10,arrowinset=1](198,-124)(270,-52)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=16,arrowwidth=10,arrowinset=1](342,-124)(270,-52)
    \Line[arrow,arrowpos=0.5,arrowlength=16,arrowwidth=10,arrowinset=1](198,20)(270,-52)
    \Text(180,-34)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\textbf{k}_1$}}}
    \Text(180,-88)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\textbf{k}_2$}}}
    \Text(324,-88)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\textbf{k}_3$}}}
    \Text(324,-34)[lb]{\Large{\Black{$\textbf{k}_4$}}}
  \end{picture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: On my updated TeXLive installation I get the lines when I compile it with latex, and then convert to ps and then to pdf.

Comment: I am using overleaf (an online tex editor). Could you suggest what I should do?